# Django how to get object in one query to database

Tags: django

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    pass

    @property
    def views_count(self):
        return PostViews.objects.filter(post=self).count()

class PostViews(models.Model):
    IPAddres= models.GenericIPAddressField(default="")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_views_count",)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def get_posts(request, topic=""):
    user = request.user
    topic = topic or LATEST
    topic = topic.lower()
    post_type = POST_TYPE.get(topic)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(status=Post.OPEN).select_related('author').prefetch_related('tags').select_related('category')
    
if topic == LATEST:
    pass
elif post_type is not None:
    posts = posts.filter(type=post_type)
elif topic == SHOW_SPAM and (user.is_authenticated and user.is_moderator):
    posts = get_spam(request)

elif topic == OPEN:
    posts = posts.filter(type=Post.QUESTION ,answer_count=0)


elif topic == MYTAGS and user.is_authenticated:
    tags = map(lambda t: t.lower(), user.my_tags.split(","))
    posts = posts.filter(tags__name__in=tags).distinct()

else:
    posts = Post.objects.none()

return posts
```

**posts.hml**

```
{% for post in posts %}
{{ post.views_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Due to the call of views, the number of sql queries grows by 10 hits.How do I get this data in place with the data received by the model Post?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have forgot the 'context' param to pass to the HTML file, that help the DTL (Django Template Language) to read the model.
Here I write an example for you:

```
def get_posts(request, topic=""):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(status=Post.OPEN).select_related('author').prefetch_related('tags').select_related('category').select_related('post_views_count')
    context = {'post': Post.object.all()}
   return render(request,'file.html',context)
```

I hope I've solved your problem, if not, please contact me I will try to help you more,
Your best.

Comment: Thanks.This is not what is needed. I have updated the question. I know the context how and when I use it. This is just a function to receive posts. not a rendering view